# How to avoid duplicate JS code that each uses its own this?

Tags: javascript, code-duplication

I have several different classes with the same duplicate code. Aside from the different identity of each's `this`, these duplicate code are all ostensibly identical.

Here's a simplified example:

```
class classA {
  ...

  doSomething() {
    if (!this.id || !this.data || !this.isAllowed()) {
      return null;
    }
    return someImportedFunc(this.data, this.metadata, this.doSomethingElse());
  }
}

class classB {
  ...

  doSomething() {
    if (!this.id || !this.data || !this.isAllowed()) {
      return null;
    }
    return someImportedFunc(this.data, this.metadata, this.doSomethingElse());
  }
}

// Many other classes like this
```

I've thought of moving the `doSomething` method to another class, then importing it in all these classes. But that would result in a very messy method that takes many, many arguments to account for all the different `this`'s. It'd look like:

```
class exportedClass {
  function doSomething(id, data, metadata, isAllowed, doSomethingElse) {
    if (!id || !data || !isAllowed()) {
      return null;
    }
    return someImportedFunc(data, metadata, doSomethingElse());
  }
}

class classA {
  ...

  methodThatUsesDoSomething() {
    const result = exportedClass.doSomething(
        this.id, this.data, this.metadata, this.isAllowed, this.doSomethingElse);
    ...
  }
}
```

Except with like 15 args instead of 5 since this is a simplified example.

How can I avoid duplicate code in this kind of situation?

Comment: Are you open to use inheritance in this case ?

Comment: *I have several different classes with the same duplicate code.* Why?

Comment: Indeed another way would be to abstract the required properties into an interface and then pass that interface to `doSomething` method... given all these classes do realize that interface as well, which should help passing `this` alone as the sole argument.

Comment: @NalinRanjan I'd prefer a non-inheritance solution to avoid a lot of refactoring. But I am open to using inheritance.

Comment: @connexo I have many different related classes extending the same superclass. These classes must all support the same functionality (but tailored to its own use case).

Comment: How is their code then *same duplicate code*? Why is this same duplicate code not part of the super class?

Comment: @connexo The superclass is owned by a different team and is used across many teams in the company. I cannot make any changes to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add mixins to ES6 javascript classes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42247434/90527), "[ES6 Class Multiple inheritance](//stackoverflow.com/q/29879267/90527)". See also the many other questions on this site about implementing multiple inheritance and mixins in JS.

Comment: Why would you need to pass any of the properties on `this`, or even `this` itself as arguments? They're already accessible via `this`. What's your understanding of objects and object fields?

Comment: @outis I cannot use an outside mixin, unless JS somehow supports dynamically determining context in a mixin function referencing `this`. (Since the mixin would need to make use of properties of the object getting extended.)

Comment: @outis I don't quite follow your follow-up question. These are instantiations of separate classes, each with its own `this`. My initial idea (with the many params) is an exported function that lives outside both `classA` and `classB`. Perhaps this was unclear, so I've edited the question.

Comment: @user3932000: In a method, `this` is bound to whichever object its called on, and is independent of the method. It's only bound to a specific object if [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is used. That is why & how mixins work, by the way.

Comment: … If you add function to an object as a property & then call it, or use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), the value of `this` within the function is bound to the appropriate object. Why do you think you need to pass an object's properties to a method? Hence my questions about your understanding of objects. This post doesn't jibe with JS's object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a non-inheritance solution, my suggestion would be to pass "this" as an argument, as prototypes can be manipulated as parameters. That would allow you to keep the parameters at a minimum while not losing data.